# Angular UI grid keeps expanding

Tags: angular-ui-grid

http://plnkr.co/edit/fxS3uQ8pGZfHUlMhoBpT?p=preview

```
<div ui-grid="routeListOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-auto-resize class="routelist">
</div>
```

Please open the plunkr in Mozilla 26 and above. I have tried versions 26,28 and 40. The Grid keeps expanding towards the right. The options for the grid are pretty basic. Not sure what is causing the issue.

Regards,

Yash

Comment: It's a long time later, but I ran into this and I found a connection with 100% and the bug. I dropped it to 99% and do not encounter the behavior. Very strange.

Comment: I changed the layout to replace TABLE with DIV.

Answer (score 0):

This is working exactly how it should work. You have given to your `td` the width 70% and because the grid is `auto-resize`, this completes all the 70% part of your screen. This is the same with your left-handside grid.

Comment: The Left TD that contains one grid has a width of 15% and not 70%. I need it to consume 15% of the screen. But not beyond that. The autoresize is added so that it resizes to fit the container TD. I have updated the plunkr to contain only one grid. Still the width of the grid keeps increasing continuously beyond the screen width.